meaning of "provision" here
This is from NPR News.

One of President Biden’s signature plans to make the internet
available to everyone is on the verge of ending. NPR’s Windsor
Johnston reports without additional funding from Congress, the
Affordable Connectivity Program is expected to run out of cash within
the next several weeks.
The program provides more than 23 million low-income households with a
monthly internet discount of at least 30 dollars and up to 75 in
high-cost areas and on tribal lands. Natalie Campbell is with the
North American Government and Regulatory Affairs for the Internet
Society.
“I don’t think that people should ever have to ask whether they're
buying groceries this month or getting internet access this month and
that is the question that I have unfortunately seen a lot of people
have to make.”
President Biden is calling on Congress to approve 6 billion dollars to
renew the program but the spending package passed last month without
the provision.

I wonder which of the following (from OALD) is the meaning of "provision" in this context.

the act of supplying somebody with something that they need or want; something that is supplied

a condition or an arrangement in a legal document



The second, although in this case it's not so much a condition as a specific item in a legal document.

Thank you very much.
